# Added Nuget packages to multi project solution template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wizard, nuget-package, project-template

After going the http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/packages-in-visual-studio-templates
I was able to configure nuGet package as a part of VSIX package for a single project template.As per the link we need to add Wizard Extension element to VSTEMPLATE of project template.

```
  <WizardExtension>
         <Assembly>NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
         <FullClassName>NuGet.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard</FullClassName>

 </WizardExtension>
```

The problem begins when I want a custom Wizard implementing IWizard interface to be binded to the project template.To do this,I need to add a dll containing IWizard implementation to GAC and add the dll details the Wizard Extension element to VSTEMPLATE of project template again.

So I want both then I will have something as below in VSTEMPLATE of project template

```
  <WizardExtension>
     <Assembly>NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
<FullClassName>NuGet.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard</FullClassName> 




  <Assembly>XXXXXXX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96268505a6009a69</Assembly>
  <FullClassName>XXXXXXX.ProjectTemplateWizard</FullClassName>

</WizardExtension>
```

In above scenario, the template will load only assembly,it does not recognize the second assembly.

Is there any way of doing it.

Regards,
Qureshi

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having 2 assenblies in 1 extensionwizard element, try having 2 wizardextension elements and a seperate wizarddata element fornuget dll.